# Template Haskell names of declarations as strings

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Say I have this:

```
f x = x + 1

tt2 name o = sequence [valD (varP (mkName name)) (normalB [| f $(varE o) |]) []]
```

I'd like to convert `tt2` to `tt`:

```
tt name o = [d| ??? = f $(varE o) |]
```

I cannot figure out what `???` should be. This is probably because I don't understand how TH works yet. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to splice a name or a pattern. Unfortunately, this is not possible. Template Haskell only allows splicing expressions, types and declarations, so you're stuck with doing it manually as in your original code.

See [GHC #1476](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1476) for some of the reasons why pattern splices are not allowed.

Comment: Okay. Do you suppose there is a more concise way to write what I have written?

Comment: @me2: Not really. You could define a helper like `simpleDecl name body = sequence [valD (varP (mkName name)) (normalB body) []]` if you need to do this in multiple places, but that's about it.